# Postscript File to Place Everything in a Layer

Tags: ghostscript, postscript, ocg, layers

Would like a postscript file that will place original pdf content onto a layer. Everything in the original pdf goes on a layer. Don't know how to place the stream into the ocg... This is the start of what I think might be the right direction.

```
% Command line to run this file:
    % Navigate to folder or include full path
        %windows cmd -> cd to folder
    %gswin32c -o MySuperPDF.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress 170-0091.pdf PDFMarkLayers.txt

% Document Open Options 
    % Defines a catalogue
        [ {Catalog}  
    % Catalogue entry that specifies that this is a Viewer Preference setting
        << /ViewerPreferences
    % Catalogue entry that defines the open option and setting
        << /HideToolbar true 
           /HideMenuBar false
           /NonFullScreenPageMode /UseOutlines >>
        >> % End of catalogue entry
    % Defines the pdfmark type as /PUT
        /PUT pdfmark 

% Set up the Page View
    % Document displays without bookmarks or thumbnails
        [ /PageMode /UseNone
    %defines which page number (starting with 1) to start on    
        /Page 1
    %Fits the page to the window            
        /View [/Fit]            
        /DOCVIEW pdfmark

% Modified from "Example: Putting a file’s contents into a text annotation"
    /F (170-0091.pdf) (r) file def
    % Create a object of type stream named 'mystream' for the data
    [ /_objdef {mystream} /type /stream /OBJ pdfmark
    % Inserts the value argument at the location index
    [ {mystream} F /PUT pdfmark
    % Create a key value that is an indirect references to the stream
    [ /MyPrivateStreamData {mystream}

% Register layer and configure its default behavior
    [{Catalog} 
        << /OCProperties 
        <</OCGs [{ocg1} {ocg2}] /D 
    <</BaseState /ON  /Order [{ocg1} {ocg2}] >> 
    >>
    >> /PUT pdfmark
    
% Just create 2 layers 
    [ /_objdef {ocg1} /type /dict /OBJ pdfmark
    [ {ocg1} <</Type/OCG /Name (My first layer)>> /PUT pdfmark
    [ /_objdef {ocg2} /type /dict /OBJ pdfmark
    [ {ocg2} <</Type/OCG /Name (My second layer)>> /PUT pdfmark
```

Comment: Not sure if this counts as a TeX question...?

Comment: There is no way to embed PDF into PostScript without converting it to EPS beforehand.

Comment: This line `[ /MyPrivateStreamData {mystream}` looks like it's missing `/PUT pdfmark` or something else. As is, it's just leaving stuff on the stack.